# How to improve command performance at runtime?

Tags: picocli

I have a library with an internal command line that uses picocli 3.9.6. One of these commands is the `log` command, which works like most loggers, taking a log level and message, and several other options. It gets called a lot in some applications that use the library, and we noticed a huge decrease in performance from when this command was implemented as a one-off vs. when it was switched to picocli. This is true even when the log level is set such that nothing interesting happens. The core code is the same between both versions.

Our suspicion, then, is that picocli is using reflection to handle each command instance. How can we improve performance? I noticed that picocli 4.x includes an annotation processor, but it's not realistic for us to make our users use Graal. Since the annotations don't change across instances, maybe they can be cached?

The code for the `log` command can be found here:

https://github.com/soartech/jsoar/blob/maven/jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/LogCommand.java

I added a `testPerformance` unit test here: https://github.com/soartech/jsoar/blob/maven/jsoar-core/src/test/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/LogCommandTest.java

Running the unit test produces times of ~3s on my machine. If I go back to commit `2bc4d39549eeb4ad69fd45e97f9607475e6426d9` (Oct 30, 2018), which is right before the `log` command was converted to picocli, and put the test in there (you can replace the entire unit test file with the newer version), I get times of ~0.03s.

Comment: I would like to help investigate this performance issue. Is the source code for the library and application publicly available? If not, can you provide a way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sorry, should have thought of that. Edit now includes it, as well as how to do the performance test.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Sorry forgot to at you with my response.

Comment: Thank you. Trying to build locally now. May need to get back to this tomorrow.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the main branch is `maven`, not `master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Java Flight Recorder to see what the hot spots are when executing the `LogCommandTest`, and I found that, indeed, what shows up at the top was essentially picocli building a model from the annotations.

Looking closer, the current application logic re-initializes a new `CommandLine` model with a new instance of `Log` for every invocation of the `LogCommand`. This is one way to  ensures that all values are reset for each invocation, but it turns out to be expensive when the command is invoked a lot. Fortunately it is not the only way.

I propose that instead, you create the `CommandLine` object once, and reuse it for all subsequent invocations. Picocli is designed to be used this way: before parsing new user input, picocli will reset options and parameters to their default values.

The patch below implements this. I focused on the `LogCommand` because this is what the OP was about, but you may want to apply a similar change to other performance-sensitive commands that are invoked a lot.

I tested the below and found that the `LogCommandTest.testPerformance` test went from 5 seconds to 0.5 seconds on my machine. The other tests in `LogCommandTest` still pass.

Proposed patch:

```
Index: jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/LogCommand.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/LogCommand.java  (revision 576ae0a1420177bad69d2f9e2e0d405c74f87ab0)
+++ jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/LogCommand.java  (date 1577052510919)
@@ -23,6 +23,7 @@
 import org.jsoar.util.commands.SoarCommandContext;
 import org.jsoar.util.commands.SoarCommandInterpreter;

+import picocli.CommandLine;
 import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
 import picocli.CommandLine.HelpCommand;
 import picocli.CommandLine.Model.CommandSpec;
@@ -39,17 +40,22 @@
 {
     private final Agent agent;
     private SoarCommandInterpreter interpreter;
+    private Log log;
+    private CommandLine logCommand;

     public LogCommand(Agent agent, SoarCommandInterpreter interpreter)
     {
         this.agent = agent;
         this.interpreter = interpreter;
+        this.log = new Log(agent, interpreter, null);
+        this.logCommand = new CommandLine(log);
     }

     @Override
     public String execute(SoarCommandContext context, String[] args) throws SoarException
     {
-        Utils.parseAndRun(agent, new Log(agent, interpreter, context), args);
+        this.log.context = context;
+        Utils.parseAndRun(agent, logCommand, args);

         return "";
     }
@@ -57,7 +63,7 @@
     @Override
     public Object getCommand()
     {
-        return new Log(agent,interpreter,null);
+        return logCommand;
     }

     @Command(name="log", description="Adjusts logging settings",
@@ -67,7 +73,7 @@
         private final Agent agent;
         private final LogManager logManager;
         private final SoarCommandInterpreter interpreter;
-        private final SoarCommandContext context;
+        private SoarCommandContext context;
         private static String sourceLocationSeparator = ".";

         @Spec
Index: jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/Utils.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/Utils.java   (revision 576ae0a1420177bad69d2f9e2e0d405c74f87ab0)
+++ jsoar-core/src/main/java/org/jsoar/kernel/commands/Utils.java   (date 1577052217242)
@@ -41,10 +41,25 @@

         parseAndRun(command, args, ps);
     }
-    
+
+    /**
+     * Executes the specified command and returns the result.
+     * A command may be a user object or a pre-initialized {@code picocli.CommandLine} object.
+     * For performance-sensitive commands that are invoked often,
+     * it is recommended to pass a pre-initialized CommandLine object instead of the user object.
+     * 
+     * @param command the command to execute; this may be a user object or a pre-initialized {@code picocli.CommandLine} object
+     * @param args the command line arguments (the first arg will be removed from this list)
+     * @param ps the PrintStream to print any command output to
+     * @return the command result
+     * @throws SoarException if the user input was invalid or if a runtime exception occurred
+     *                      while executing the command business logic
+     */
     public static List<Object> parseAndRun(Object command, String[] args, PrintStream ps) throws SoarException {

-        CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(command);
+        CommandLine commandLine = command instanceof CommandLine
+                ? (CommandLine) command
+                : new CommandLine(command);

         // The "debug time" command takes a command as a parameter, which can contain options
         // In order to inform picocli that the options are part of the command parameter
```

Comment: Thank you so much! While it still seems 10x slower than the pre-picocli version in the unit test (but 10x faster than it was before), in an actual application the performance is back to the pre-picocli version. Presumably this means that either my test is not very good, or the performance of `log` is no longer very relevant to the application's performance. Either way, I'd say problem solved (unless you have other ideas on how to improve things further).

Comment: You’re welcome. The performance of the actual application is of course what matters. To get more insight into performance bottlenecks in the application, I recommend running the full application with Java Flight Recorder: that usually allows you to zoom in fast. If you want to dig deeper, the excellent JMH library may help avoid some common pitfalls in benchmarking Java code. Glad that the immediate issue seems resolved!

Comment: Also, if you have a chance, I recommend upgrading to the latest version of picocli. [4.0](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/releases/tag/v4.0.0) had many improvements, and later releases added even more nice features. Enjoy! :-)